# how to find index of duplicates items in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am having a with graph, i need to remove duplicates values from array and "0" as well and i want to adjust array according to that for example

```swift
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    var unique: [Element] {
        var uniqueValues: [Element] = []
        forEach { item in
            if !uniqueValues.contains(item) {
                uniqueValues += [item]
            }
        }
        return uniqueValues
    }
}

let speed = [0, 10, 20, 20, 40, 50, 50 ,50, 80, 90, 100]
let time = ["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]

speed.unique // Return Only Unique Values
```

Now i want my time array to be updated.
Example 
Index : 0, 3 - is removed from speed 
i want to remove index 0, 3 from time as well

Comment: Use one array of `struct` where the `struct` has `speed` and `time` properties. Then you much more easily sort and filter the array of struct. When done you could create the two final arrays from the final array of `struct`.

Comment: i am using speed as struct and time as [String], but no luck :(

Comment: Please read my comment again. You want one struct with both values and a single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let speed = [  0,   10,   20,   20,   40,   50,   50,   50,   80,   90,  100]
let time =  ["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]

var sp = [Int]()
var tm = [String]()

for (i, x) in speed.enumerated() {
    if !sp.contains(x) {
        sp.append(x)
        tm.append(time[i])
    }
}

print(sp) //[  0,   10,   20,   40,   50,   80,   90,  100]
print(tm) //["9", "10", "11", "13", "15", "18", "19", "20"]
```

Choosing an appropriate type for `time` is advisable.

It is recommended in object-oriented programming to have speed and time as properties of a struct:

```
struct Mover {
    let speed: Int
    let time : TimeInterval
}
```

For example given this array:

```
let movers = [Mover(speed:   0, time:  9),
              Mover(speed:  10, time: 10),
              Mover(speed:  20, time: 11),
              Mover(speed:  20, time: 12),
              Mover(speed:  40, time: 13),
              Mover(speed:  50, time: 15),
              Mover(speed:  50, time: 16),
              Mover(speed:  50, time: 17),
              Mover(speed:  80, time: 18),
              Mover(speed:  90, time: 19),
              Mover(speed: 100, time: 20)]
```

You could keep the elements with a unique speed this way:

```
var speeds = Set<Int>()

let moversUniqueSpeed = movers.filter { speeds.insert($0.speed).inserted }
```

Comment: i am so dumb why didn't i thought about this, Thank you very much.